# Proof of inequality $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\binom n k\frac{5^k}{5^k+1}\ge\frac{2^n\cdot 5^n}{3^n+5^n}$

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients

Show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom n k\frac{5^k}{5^k+1}\ge\frac{2^n\cdot 5^n}{3^n+5^n}$$

where $$\binom n k=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that the LHS is
$$
(\ast)=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\frac1{1+5^{-k}}=2^n\cdot\mathbb E\left(\frac1{1+5^{-S_n}}\right),
$$
where the random variable $S_n$ is binomial $\left(n,\frac12\right)$. Since the function $x\mapsto\frac1{1+x}$ is convex on $x\geqslant0$, Jensen's inequality yields
$$
(\ast)\geqslant\frac{2^n}{1+\mathbb E\left(5^{-S_n}\right)}.
$$
Now, $S_n$ is distributed as $X_1+\cdots+X_n$ for some i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables $(X_k)_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n}$ such that $\mathbb P(X_k=0)=\mathbb P(X_k=1)=\frac12$. One gets $\mathbb E\left(5^{-X_k}\right)=\frac12\left(1+\frac15\right)=\frac35$ and, by independence, $\mathbb E\left(5^{-S_n}\right)=\left(\frac35\right)^n$. This proves the claim.

Comment: Nice.:-D During my student years I studied much more analysis than the theory of probability. :-)

Comment: It's nice, Thank you +1

Answer (score 9):

It seems that we can prove the inequality as follows: $$S=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom n k\dfrac{5^k}{5^k+1}=$$
$$\frac 12+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom n k\dfrac{1}{1+5^{-k}}=$$
$$\frac 12+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom n k\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i(5^{-k})^i=$$
$$\frac 12+\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom n k (-1)^i5^{-ki}=$$
$$\frac 12+\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom n k (-1)^i5^{-ik}=$$
$$\frac 12+\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i((1+5^{-i})^n-1).$$

Since the last series is alternating, its sum is greater than the sum of its four first members. Therefore
$$S\ge \frac 12+(2^n-1)-\left(\left(\frac 65\right)^n-1\right)+\left(\left(\frac {26}{25}\right)^n-1\right)-\left(\left(\frac {126}{125}\right)^n-1\right)=$$
$$2^n-\left(\frac 65\right)^n+\left(\frac {26}{25}\right)^n-\left(\frac {126}{125}\right)^n+\frac 12.$$

Check when $$2^n-\left(\frac 65\right)^n+\left(\frac {26}{25}\right)^n-\left(\frac {126}{125}\right)^n\ge \frac{2^n\cdot 5^n}{3^n+5^n}.$$

After reducing both sides to the common denominator and simplifying we obtain the inequality
$$650^n+390^n\ge 630^n+450^n+378^n.$$ But $$650^6>630^6+450^6+378^6,$$ thus the inequality holds for each $n\ge 6$.

It rests to check the initial inequality for $n\le 5$, which can be done straightforward.

Comment: The last part is even easier to show: on LHS you have $(5 \cdot 26)^n=130^n$, on RHS $90^n-78^n$, which is clearly less than LHS

Comment: It's nice! Thank you +1

Comment: The first term in line 2 should be $\frac 1 2$ instead of 1, is not so?

Comment: @user64494 Yes. Thanks. I'll correct this.

Comment: When the last term one keeps in an alternating series is positive, the sum of the series is *smaller* than the truncated sum, not larger.

Comment: @Did Thanks. I try to correct this.

Comment: Good luck, maybe keeping one more term is enough? (But I must admit that upvotes on MSE are as fascinating as ever...)